# response.redirect not re-directing, just posting back to current page

Tags: response.redirect

I have a JavaScript function that is manually calling a postback: __doPostBack('ctl00$searchButton', '');

The above searchButton is on a Master page and has an onclick event wired up. At the end of the event, I am re-directing to another page. This re-direct fails when the postback is called from JS. It works properly when the onclick is fired normally. I'm moving away from the auto fire in order to perform some client-side operations that are drastically reducing the HTML mark-up. I have tried replacing the Response.Redirect with a Server.Transfer with no success.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Is the rest of the code behind in the function being run when you manually call the __doPostBack ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting a debugging session and setting a breakpoint on that pages Load() method and seeing what the execution path is.

Also, try an HTTP proxy (HttpFox for FireFox plugin, Charles Proxy for an OS level proxy) to see what exactly the redirects are doing.